# statkc trace with static variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the following code, if I put a breakpoint in the static constructor
of Class3, i don't see the constructor of Class1 in the visual studio stack trace.  If I replace the line var test = Class2.c3 with var test = new Class2()
I see it.  Why is that ?

[image: stacktrace]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var c1 = new Class1();
}

class Class1
{
   public Class1()
   {
      var test = Class2.c3;
   }
}

class Class2
{
   public static Class3 c3 = new Class3();

}

class Class3
{
   static Class3()
   {
     Console.WriteLine("test");
   }
}
```

Comment: You dont have an instance constructor for `Class3`, yet you instantiate it in `Class2`

Comment: The constructor is the default, parameterless public constructor provided by the compiler.

Comment: ok i put the break point on var test = Class2.c3 and see that it was it after.  Now I understand the order in which things are hit.  thanks